# Whmcs friendly URL setting will not work with nginx. How can I fix this?

Tags: whmcs, nginx-config

I am trying to setup full friendly urls on whmcs, but I can not get the configuration to work. I have tried various configurations but none seems to work, and the ones that do work break other things, such as the admin urls.

https://whmcs.community/topic/291496-moderncurrent-76-nginx-rules/
I have tried this, but it does not work for all URLs

Answer (score 0):

Try these configurations

```
    location ~ /billing/announcements/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/announcements/$1;
}

location ~ /billing/downloads/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/downloads/$1;
}

location ~ /billing/knowledgebase/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/knowledgebase/$1;
}

location ~ /billing/store/ssl-certificates/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/store/ssl-certificates/$1;
}

location ~ /billing/store/sitelock/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/store/sitelock/$1;
}

location ~ /billing/store/website-builder/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/store/website-builder/$1;
}

location ~ /billing/store/order/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/store/order/$1;
}

location ~ /billing/download/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/download$1;
}

location ~ /billing/cart/domain/renew/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/cart/domain/renew$1;

}

location ~ /billing/knowledgebase/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/knowledgebase/$1;
}

location ~ /billing/store/ssl-certificates/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/store/ssl-certificates/$1;
}

location ~ /billing/store/sitelock/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/store/sitelock/$1;
}

location ~ /billing/store/website-builder/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/store/website-builder/$1;
}

location ~ /billing/store/order/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/store/order/$1;
}

location ~ /billing/download/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/download$1;
}

location ~ /billing/admin/setup/authn/view/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/admin/index.php?rp=/admin/setup/authn/view/$1;
}

location ~ /billing/admin/apps/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/admin/index.php?rp=/admin/apps$1;
}

location ~ /billing/admin/setup/notifications/overview/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/admin/index.php?rp=/admin/setup/notifications/overview$1;
}

location ~ /billing/admin/setup/storage/index/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/admin/index.php?rp=/admin/setup/storage/index$1;
}

location ~ /billing/admin/setup/payments/tax/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/admin/index.php?rp=/admin/setup/payments/tax$1;
}

location ~ /billing/admin/help/license/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/admin/index.php?rp=/admin/help/license$1;
}

location ~ /billing/admin/setup/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/admin/index.php?rp=/admin/setup$1;
}
location ~ /billing/admin/utilities/system/php-compat/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/admin/index.php?rp=/admin/utilities/system/php-compat$1;
}

location ~ /billing/admin/services/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/admin/index.php?rp=/admin/services$1;
}

location ~ /billing/admin/services/shared/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/admin/index.php?rp=/admin/services/shared$1;
}

location ~ /billing/admin/services/reseller/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/admin/index.php?rp=/admin/services/reseller$1;
}

location ~ /billing/admin/services/server/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/admin/index.php?rp=/admin/services/server$1;
}

location ~ /billing/admin/services/other/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/admin/index.php?rp=/admin/services/other$1;
}

location ~ /billing/admin/addons/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/admin/index.php?rp=/admin/addons$1;
}

location ~ /billing/admin/domains/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/admin/index.php?rp=/admin/domains$1;
}
```

[Reference](https://hostup.org/blog/whmcs-friendly-urls-configuration-for-nginx/)

Answer (score 0):

please what convert to .htaccess?
EX

```
location ~ /billing/store/sitelock/?(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?rp=/store/sitelock/$1;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).